# Не получается вытянуть значение из JSON

Tags: java, json

получаю из JSON строку вида:
{"base":"USD","date":"2018-03-01","rates":{"RUB":56.839}}
далее пытаюсь вытащить значение из RUB

```
JSONObject ratesObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);
System.out.println(ratesObj.get("rates"));

JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) ratesObj.get("rates");
JSONObject RUB_OBJ = (JSONObject) arr.get(0);
System.out.println(RUB_OBJ.get("RUB"));
```

Вылетает:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray

Подскажите как правильно вытянуть значение из RUB?

Comment: В вашем JSON объекте `rates` - не массив, а объект. Если вы ожидаете, что там будет массив, то объект должен был быть таким: `{"base":"USD","date":"2018-03-01","rates":[{"RUB":56.839}]}` (всё внимание на квадратные скобки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же не массив (у вас строковый ключ), о чем и говорит компилятор.

```
JSONObject ratesObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);
JSONObject rates = (JSONObject) ratesObj.get("rates");
System.out.println(rates.get("RUB"));
```

Comment: Благодарю, затупил) тема для меня новая.